# Markdown: how to syntax-highlight Bold and Italic in different color than normal text?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown

Text marked as`__bold__` or `_italic_` appears in the same color as normal text.

Headings and code do show up in different colors, so vim correctly recognizes the file as markdown.

This is no matter what colorscheme I use.

Is it possible to make text marked as bold or italic in Markdown, highlighted in their own colors?

P.S. I'm using a full vim install (not vim-tiny) version 7.4 on Xubuntu Linux.

This is what it looks like. While the previous lines show that headings etc. work, line 22-26 contain text that should have been highlighted differently than the default - this is in `:colorscheme default` but it doesn't work in others either

[image]

Comment: If you think you can have some use for pandoc, you can check (at least) the syntax plugin: https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax . It will show bold as bold, italic as italic (or IIRC with different background color in terminals without italic support). Or at least you can check its syntax for hints.

Comment: What's the output of `:verbose highlight htmlBold` and `:verbose highlight htmlItalic`? These should be the default highlight groups if you're using the builtin markdown support.

Comment: I have the same problem when I use `vim` from `xterm` with `markdown` or `html` files. But if I start `tmux` inside the same `xterm` it works as expected. Doing `:set ft=html` seems to fix it (the `filetype` already was HTML).  `:highlight htmlBold` says `cleared` *but many other `html*` highlights are fine) ... Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: @zool they both say `xxx cleared` - does that mean the builtin markdown support is not working?

Comment: @VanLaser I tried installing pandoc but couldn't get it to work...

Comment: @LB7979 I don't think so, no. Doesn't it say cleared by what? `verbose` usually says where an option got last set. If you find out that you can usually fix the issue.

Comment: @zool It says `Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/html.vim` for both Bold and Italic

Comment: @zool No sorry, what I meant to say was just ran the command again and now it says `htmlBold xxx term=bold cterm=Bold gui=bold Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/html.vim` and the same with Italic. Last time I ran it it just said cleared, and nothing about Last set.

Comment: In my case, the problem is caused by: `colorscheme default` in my vimrc ... If I remove this it works as expected.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like that:

```
highlight htmlBold gui=bold guifg=#af0000 ctermfg=124
highlight htmlItalic gui=italic guifg=#ff8700 ctermfg=214
```

Comment: Sorry for this late reply, but just wanted to let you know that in the meantime I've had to reinstall Kubuntu (for reasons unrelated to the above issue) and in this completely fresh install of Kubuntu/konsole/vim the syntax highlighting works perfect. So the problem is solved, but I don't know what caused it in the first place, and unfortunately I can't let you know if your suggestion would have worked...

Comment: @LB7979 Ok, no problem. Good luck :).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Vim default color schemes don't have the best support for markdown and use the HTML syntax file instead. That's probably causing your issue.

Try installing a maintained and popular color scheme instead. [Solarized](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized), [Monokai](https://github.com/sickill/vim-monokai) and [base16](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-vim) are common choices.

Comment: I installed those colorschemes, but when I activate them within Vim, it gives many error messages

`Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/base16-eighties.vim:

line    4:
E477: No ! allowed: <!DOCTYPE html>

line    5:
E488: Trailing characters: <html lang=

line    6:
E488: Trailing characters:   <head prefix=

line    7:
E488: Trailing characters:     <meta charset='utf-8'>`

etc. Looks like it actually recognized it's not an html file.

Comment: LB7979 Well, it looks like you downloaded some HTML file, and not the colorscheme... I don't think this is your problem though, as bold text should always work regardless of colorscheme...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think that's exactly the problem. The output of `:verb hi htmlBold` on my machine is this: `ctermfg=3 guifg=#ebcb8b Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/base16-vim/colors/base16-ocean.vim`, so the color gets clearly set by my color scheme. Please compare my output to the one of @LB7979, where `htmlBold xxx term=bold cterm=Bold gui=bold Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/html.vim`. No mention of color highlighting in Vim's  default HTML syntax. The `bold` setting is probably not working either cause bold text rendering is off by default in most terminal emulators.

Comment: @LB7979 please try giving `:hi htmlBold ctermfg=#ff0000 guifg=#ff0000` and check if bold text in your buffer turns red.

Comment: @LB7979 Also, you can enable bold text rendering in iTerm2 by checking Preferences > Profiles > Text > Draw bold text in bold font

Comment: @LB7979 I have no idea what you did there, but to successfully install a color scheme your best bet is following the installation instruction. Here are the ones for Solarized: https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#installation

Comment: @zool Regarding the downloaded color schemes: I downloaded them again, followed the installation instructions (put the solarized.vim file in folder ~/.vim/colors) but still get these error messages, I don't understand...

Comment: @zool The command `:hi htmlBold ctermfg=#ff0000 guifg=#ff0000` gives the following error message: `E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermfg=#ff0000 guifg=#ff0000`

Comment: "Allow bold text" is checked in Terminal preferences, so that is definitely not the problem. I'm trying in both gnome-terminal and xfce4-terminal btw.

Comment: @zool @LB7979 Me too: `E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermfg=#ff0000 guifg=#ff0000`